# MongoDB aggregate turn list into boolean

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need a query in MongoDB where I turn a list into True or False depending on whether a value exists in the list or not.

Here's a summarized view of the schema.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('604edf91571e7ab19cc2c238'),
 'timestamp': 1616164767.773929,
 'name': 'some name',
 'metric1': 1,
 'metric2': 2,
 'metric3': 3,
 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag that matters']}
```

Is there a way to change the tags key to a value of True or False if a `'tag that matters'` is in the list? I don't want to exclude records that don't have the tag, I just want those records to have a value of False for the tags key.

Comment: Use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/ with a $set stage.

Comment: @D.SM Works. Thank you.

Comment: Are you expecting an array of `True` or `False` as in Python? because in javascript its `true` or `false`. Then I need to modify the query lil bit.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat Yea I should have had Python in the tags, but your answer is good I can follow it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to use an `$in` operator in the project stage.

```
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "timestamp": "$timestamp",
        "name": "$name",
        "metric1": "$metric1",
        "metric2": "$metric2",
        "metric3": "$metric3",
        "tags": {
            "$in": ["tag that matters", "$tags"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "tags": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$tags",
                    as: "tag",
                    in: {
                        $eq: ['$$tag', 'tag that matters']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604edf91571e7ab19cc2c238"),
    "timestamp" : 1616164767.773929,
    "name" : "some name",
    "metric1" : 1,
    "metric2" : 2,
    "metric3" : 3,
    "tags" : [
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true
    ]
}
```